# how React native horizontal list pick center element id and show on screen

Tags: listview, react-native, uipickerview, react-native-flatlist, snapchat

there is a flatlist/listview ,i made it horizontal ,now i wanna get id of item which is on view in middle like in snap chat we select lens selection ,Is there any way to achieve that?

[i have associated image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2ZRd.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

i solved it , Using horizontal scroll view with some function of scrollview like, snapToInterval(causes the scroll view to stop at multiples of the value of snapToInterval),scrollEventThrottle(This controls how often the scroll event will be fired while scrolling (as a time interval in ms))

Comment: I see that Flatlist also has those props did you necessarily need to migrate to listview? Could you please share a snippet of your code?